# C# adding space after few characters in string

Tags: character, space

I wanna add space in string( string from array) after 2 characters, for example:
`1234567890` should be `12 34 56 78 90`, any suggestions how to do that?

Comment: If this is a homework question you should say so so that we can give you the appropriate level of help, if not, George's answer will work great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would probably have to do a loop as such:

```
int i = 0;
int amount = 2;
string s = "1234567890";
string withspaces = "";

while (i+amount < s.Length) {
  s += s.Substring(i,i+amount);
  s += " ";
  i = i + amount;
}
```

This could be heavy on string usage, so make sure you read up on effective string concatenation

Answer (score 4):

```
"0123567236359783590203582835"
.ToCharArray()
.Aggregate("",
(result, c) => result += ((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result) && (result.Length+1) % 3 == 0)
                          ? " " : "")
                         + c.ToString()
            );

// --> 01 23 56 72 36 35 97 83 59 02 03 58 28 35
```

Comment: You're awersome!

Answer (score 0):

If your looking specifically to format a fixed amount of numbers, such as the example above, the following will fit your needs.

```
int n = 1234567890;
string s = String.Format("{0:00 00 00 00 00}", n);
```

Note, this assumes that your `1234567890` is stored as a number.  It will not format if `n` is of type `string`.  You can overcome this by casting `n` to a number prior to formatting.

If you have an unbounded number of characters, you'll need a more versitile solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend following steps

1. Create a For loop which will go through the length of input string.
2. During each run of For loop concat ith elemen of string in to the result i.e.

   result+=input[i];
3. Inside for loop keep track of count and after every `count%2 == 0` concat space to the result.

   result+=" ";

Hope this helps.